# php test script via jquery, passing values to php file

Tags: php, jquery

topic is not clear but ı will try to explain.

ı am working on php test-quiz script. ı want to do it with jquery and php. ı am listing question and answer inside a form.

when you submit form ı am sending them to `test.php` via `$.ajax()` and take them with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but the problem is if someone dont chose answer its dont passing empty value. so ı can calculate just answered question.

this is my codes:

```
$data=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

ı am working with this data but its not included unanswered question so ı cant calculate point.

html+php part:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="form">

 <?php 

$sorgu=mysql_query("select * from question");
         $i=1;
                while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sorgu))
                {

                    $id=$s["id"];
                    $soru=$s["soru"];


                        $csorgu=mysql_query("select * from answer where q_id='$id'");

                        echo $i."-) ".$Question;
                        $i+=1;
                            while($c=mysql_fetch_array($csorgu))
                                {

                                    $soru_id=$c["soru_id"];
                                    $answer=$c["cevap"];
                                    $d=$c["d"];
                                    $cid=$c["id"];


                            ?>  

  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $soru_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>"  />
      <?php echo $answer; ?></label>
    <label>

  </p>


<?php
}

                }
                ?>
                </form>
```

jquery:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){

var myRadio = $("#form1 input[type='radio']:checked").val();
var form=($('#form1').serialize());



    $.ajax({
          type:"get",           
          url: "test.php?do=test",
          data:form,
          success: function(result){

            alert(result);
                                    }   
    });
```

you dont need but my point calculating system:

```
$data=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];



$data2=explode("&",$data); 

for ($i=0;$i<count($data2);$i++)
{
    $seri = explode("=", $data2[$i]);
    $seri_dizi[$i]=$seri[1];
}
unset($seri_dizi[0]);

$answer = array_count_values($seri_dizi);
@$false_answer=($answer["0"]);
$total_question=count($seri_dizi);

if($false_answer=" ") $false_answer=0;

$correct_answer=$total_question-$false_answer;
```

ı know correct answer and wrong answer but ı dont know how many question didnt unanswered

if you have any solution ı am here.

Comment: You don't need to split stuff from `$_SERVER`, php does it already for you in `$_GET` array.

Comment: ı know but ı have to many value. ı cant use it.

Comment: For as many you have, `$_GET` will do, even if you have nested arrays.

Comment: yes but how? $_GET["1"] $_GET["2"] $_GET["3"] $_GET["4"] $_GET["n"]

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)`, inspect what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be to add a "Not answered" response to your questions, checked by default, just like this :

For instance :

```
 <input type="radio" name="my_question_1" value="0" checked/> Not answered
 <input type="radio" name="my_question_1" value="1"/> The first answer
 <input type="radio" name="my_question_1" value="2"/> The second answer
```